# How does "Come on!" translates in Russian?

Tags: перевод

I can't understand how "Come on!" translates in Russian. I found this phrase in two films. One film says it translates as "Хорошо!" and other says "Давай!". Google Translate shows "Ну же!" or "Давай!". 
What is the most suitable phrase?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the context, therefore **`come on`** alone isn't enough for accurate translation

As a prompt for action it's **`давай`**. As a repeated prompt it can be rendered as **`ну же`**

As a condescending or skeptical dismissal it's **`да ладно (тебе)`**, **`да брось (ты)`**